# Seting property of class

Tags: excel, vba, class

I have two classes

class Table which countains 2 informations (name and value)

```
    Option Explicit
Private dName As String
Private dValue As Double
Property Get Name() As String
Name = dName
End Property
Property Let Name(Jmeno As String)
dName = Jmeno
End Property

Property Get Value() As Double
Value = dValue
End Property
Property Let Value(Hodnota As Double)
dValue = Hodnota
End Property
```

and main class where I use objects(in array) of class Table.

```
Option Explicit
Private dklicovaTeplota() As cls_Table

Property Get KlicovaTeplota(pozice As Integer) As cls_Table
Set KlicovaTeplota = dklicovaTeplota(pozice)
End Property

Property Set KlicovaTeplota(pozice As Integer, Jmeno As String, Hodnota As Double)
Dim temp As New cls_Table
temp.Name = Jmeno
temp.Value = Hodnota
Set dklicovaTeplota(pozice) = temp

End Property
```

When I run code I get error:
[image: ERROR]

And when I come back to VBA editor the

```
Property Set KlicovaTeplota(pozice As Integer, Jmeno As String, Hodnota As Double)
```

is marked.
I have no idea where my property setting is inconsistent..

Comment: The Get and Set for a given Property must be of the same datatype: if the Get returns a cls_Table object then the Set must accept the same object type.  Instead of a Set,  use an `AddTable` Sub which accepts the parameters currently in your Set method.

Comment: Also at some point you need to dimension the array `dklicovaTeplota()`